# Limitar la cantidad de decimales javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente problema, tengo este script y el resultado me sale con muchos decimales, hay alguna manera de solucionar eso?

[image: Ejemplo del resultado]

ejemplo
$1,500,000 * 0.20%(0.002) = $3,000 
De esos 3,000 le sumo el iva
$3,000 * 1.16% = 3,480 pero me aparece asi (3479.9999999999995)

```js
<script>
    function calcular(){
  //Obtienes el valor
  var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;
  var valor2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;

  var result= document.getElementById('result');
  var total= document.getElementById('total');

  //le descuentas el 8% y lo agregas al HTML
  var descuento = parseInt(valor)*valor2;
  var iva = parseInt(valor)*valor2*1.16;
        
  //agrega los resultados al DOM
  result.innerHTML = + descuento;
  resulta2.innerHTML = + iva;
  resultado3.innerHTML = iva - descuento;
}
    </script>
```

Comment: agrega el html y el código js para poder ayudarte, de otro modo no es posible

Comment: Tal como te comentan para poder ayudarte mejor agrega tu codigo HTML  y JavaScript para dar  una posible solución, edita tu pregunta aqui: "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248670/edit"

Comment: Puedes usar la funcion `toFixed()` para redondear el numero resultante a la cantidad de decimales que necesites

Comment: Genial amigo, ya quedo!!! Gracias a todos

Answer (score 3):

debes usar el metodo [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed) que recibe como parametro la cantidad de decimales que deseas

**ejemplo:**

```js
let number =999.8712341
let dos_decimales = number.toFixed(2)
console.log(dos_decimales)
```